# Why is my data not stripping properly with mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code below:

```
    $studentTalking = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentTalking']);

    //Finally, we can actually the field with the student's information
    $sql = <<<SQL
    UPDATE `database` SET
        `studentName`='$studentName',
        `studentEmail`='{$data['studentEmail']}',
        `studentPhone`='{$data['studentPhone']}',
        `studentID`='{$data['studentID']}',
        `studentTalking`= '{$studentTalking}',
        `resume` = '{$data['resume']}'
    WHERE `id`={$data['date_time']} AND (`studentName` IS NULL OR `studentName`='')
SQL;
```

I am trying to use the mysql_real_escape_string to allow apostrophes entered into our form by the user to go to the database without breaking the database, however the data will either go through as null or the apostrophe will break the database. I have changed everything I could think of, and can't figure out why this isn't working. Yes I understand the that injections could break our database, and we will work on updating the code soon to mysqli but we need this working now. I suspect my syntax isn't correct and the first line may need to be moved somewhere, but I am not the strongest in PHP and I am working with code that was written by previous interns. Thank you in advance.

Comment: switch to `mysqli`. The `mysql` functions are bad and deprecated

Comment: It's trying to tell you not to use `mysql_*` and to use prepared statements with `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.....

Comment: If you are setting `$studentTalking` in the first line of code there then why is your SQL statement still using `$_POST['studentTalking']`?

Comment: The server is run by another department, and as much as I would love to have it updated it is out of my control. Is there no way to do this in the meantime while I attempt to convince our server management team to do the upgrade?

Comment: All values are NULL or empty? How are the other variables set?

Comment: @chris85 all values are correct except studentTalking, which comes in as blank not NULL.

Comment: Okay, and `$_POST` is populated? The other variables are `$data`..

Comment: It should be an easy sell

Answer (score 4):

Switch to `mysqli_*` functions is the right answer.

The answer if intend to stayg with the deprecated and dangerous `mysql_*` functions:

---

Here you set a new variable equal to your escaped `$_POST[]`:

```
$studentTalking = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentTalking']);
```

But in your SQL you still refer to the $_POST array... Switch your SQL over to use your new variable you created

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    UPDATE `tgtw_rsvp` SET
        `studentName`='$studentName',
        `studentEmail`='{$data['studentEmail']}',
        `studentPhone`='{$data['studentPhone']}',
        `studentID`='{$data['studentID']}',
        `studentTalking`= '$studentTalking',
        `resume` = '{$data['resume']}'
    WHERE `id`={$data['date_time']} AND (`studentName` IS NULL OR `studentName`='')
SQL;
```

Comment: I have just changed that line to what you suggested, and the error has gone away, but the data gets sent to the database as blank

Comment: How about, instead of bothering with the database for debugging, you just echo this $studentTalking and it's respective $_POST[] out and see what's going on. Something funky is happening and that may help troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not using the stripped variable but still the raw POST data.

Comment: I have changed that part, and the error has gone away, but the data is sent over as blank

Comment: Please add a var_dump($sql) and post it here.